# Удаление из массива нескольких записей по общему значению элемента

Tags: php, массивы

Есть у меня вот такая штука:

```
$user = $wall->response;
print_r($user);
```

В ответ приходит при выполнении вот это:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 1234567892
>   [friend_status] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 48359869
>   [friend_status] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 123456744
>   [friend_status] => 0 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] =>
>   1236544885 [friend_status] => 0 ) )

Мне необходимо удалить из этого массива все записи имеющие `[friend_status] => 3`,либо же `2`, либо же `1`. И оставить только пользователей со значением `0`.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать на примере )

Comment: `array_filter` ?

Comment: `array_filter` Покажите пожалуйста как его на моём примере конкретно использовать и фильтровать по трём значениям.

Comment: `return !$tem->friend_sttus`

Answer (score 1):

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($user, function($element) {
    return $element->friend_status == 0;
});
```

Примерно такое Вам нужно написать.

Comment: Только достаточно написать `return $element->friend_status == 0`

Comment: точно! спасибо, исправил

Comment: `print_r($filteredArray); ` и потом это выводить?

Comment: Ну тоесть работать с ним.

Comment: @PHPcoder Да, потом уже работать с отфильтрованным массивом `$filteredArray` ибо там результат фильтрации лежит... мануальчик: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php